# How to update existing excel xls format Fields using C#

Tags: c#, excel

Update Specified Fields in Existing Excel File using C# .NET (.XLS) Format

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code and please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how-to-create-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer

Comment: Even a brief code snippet would help identify where to start and how to help.  Right now, this is extremely general.  Is this interop?

Answer (score 0):

I Just Want to update Existing Excel File using C# .NET (.XLS) Format

This code is working fine Thanks

```
String sConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + newFile + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO'";
OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);
objConn.Open();

OleDbCommand selectCmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", objConn);

OleDbDataAdapter xlAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
xlAdapter.SelectCommand = selectCmd;

DataSet xlDataset = new DataSet();

xlAdapter.Fill(xlDataset, "XLData");

xlAdapter.Dispose();
selectCmd.Dispose();

var thisDates = fDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Trim() + " TO " +
                                    tDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Trim();

OleDbCommand cmdUpDates = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Sheet1$C5:C5] SET F1='" + thisDates + "'", objConn);
cmdUpDates.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmdUpDates.Dispose();

var totalRows = xlDataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

for (int z = 0; z < totalRows; z++)
{
    DataRow item = xlDataset.Tables[0].Rows[z];

    Int32 oQtyBon = 0;

    var idx = z + 1;

    OleDbCommand cmdUpOpening = new OleDbCommand
    ("UPDATE [Sheet1$E" + idx + ":E" + idx + "] SET F1=" + oQtyBon, objConn);
    cmdUpOpening.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmdUpOpening.Dispose();
}

objConn.Close();
objConn.Dispose();
```